# Using packagemaker to combine multiple packages under one

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am making an installer for Mac, and I need to distribute multiple packages under one. But the problem is that when I drag the packages on the Contents pane of the Package Maker, they are marked with "?"

So can anyone wxplain me how to do something like this.
I am using the latest version of Package Maker on Lion.